# Is there anyway to check how long microtasks take to execute?

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native, xcode-instruments, javascriptcore

I would like to time a function which will spawn a bunch of microtasks. I would like to time how long the microtasks took to execute and exclude the idle time that the event loop was empty. It's impractical to find every line of code that queues a microtask so I need a general way of measuring the blocking time spent by microtasks while the function was running.

How can I do that?

I would be interested in how to do this in any engine but most interested in react native with JavaScript core. Perhaps possible with Xcode instruments?

Comment: You can use moment library to record the start time & end time and get the difference. This way you'll get the time taken to execute micro tasks.

Comment: I don't think you've understood @KushalDesai also I would not advise moment for measuring performance. `performance.now` would be more advisable

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Flipper](https://fbflipper.com/) .There you can test the performance, how much components are rendered in time and functions are performed.

Comment: I've seen Flipper but not using it at the moment. I'm not interested in components right now. Will it measure microtask performance?

Comment: As I can see yes. You can find section performance.It's similar to the section that is on the web

Comment: I've installed it but it's not very helpful. I'm specifically trying to measure the amount of blocking time vs idle tame taken up by the JS thread on iOS during a series of microtasks. If you can explain how to do that that would be very helpful.